# Rep scores are displayed wrong, higher as they should

Tags: bug, reputation-history

When sorting by time, some rep scores appear to be too high (not for my personal taste but for logic), the sum is correct though. Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your bug report... What is wrong with the scores? You are saying that they don't match the scores on the associated posts?

Comment: I think this is a known bug. This page stopped being accurate in December

Comment: @CodyGray Yes the "high scores" currently should be 40 and 80 instead of 80 and 150.

Comment: This is what I see https://i.stack.imgur.com/CafTy.jpg

Comment: Possible dupe on MSE: [Ghost (nonexistent) votes in reputation tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377620/241919) and [its linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/377620?sort=newest).

Comment: @Dharman Funny, now it's right for me too. The ghost must have fixed it in the meantime.

Comment: That only happens when the page is trying to show you new reputation changes. Come back when you receive an upvote and it will be broken again.

Comment: Oh, I see why I was confused. You thought that the redesigned profile pages were actually functional. No, not in any way whatsoever. They're now just for looks, and they don't even look good.

Comment: Yes, this keeps happening, seemingly when I have new votes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz1Ch.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RgQP.png

Comment: @Cody Gray: But "we" don't want [vanity metrics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive).

Comment: I thought vanity was half of the point of Stack Overflow. It's not like I can buy dinner with my rep.

Comment: @PeterMortensen so votes are valued much as "Lies, Damn Lies and Statistics"...

Comment: @SolarMike well they are definitely statistics.